# add new key value pair to empty object throws TypeError is null error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

Here is my mobx store that I am trying to use in a react apps:

```
import {observable, computed, action, decorate} from 'mobx';

class Cart {
    cart = 0;
    product = {};
    loaded = false;


    addCart(product, amount) {
        if(this.product === null) {
            this.product[product] = Number(amount);
        } else {
            if (product in this.product) {
                this.product[product] = this.product[product] + Number(amount);
            } else {
                this.product[product] = Number(amount);
            }
        }
        localStorage.setItem('product', JSON.stringify(this.product));
        this.cart = this.cart + Number(amount);
    }
}

export default Cart = decorate(Cart, {
    cart: observable,
    product: observable,
    addCart: action
})
```

when I tried to add some data from component like `addCart(4, 1)` it throws `TypeError: this.product is null`  and error shows in this block

```
if(this.product === null) {
   this.product[product] = Number(amount);
}
```

Comment: this.product = [] try adding this before this.product[product] = Number(amount);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this.product is null, you have to first set it equal to an empty array before you assign an array element:

```
addCart(product, amount) {
    if(this.product === null) {
        this.product = [];  // <-- INSERT THIS LINE HERE
        this.product[product] = Number(amount);
```